# PHP 5.6 to PHP 5.4 downgrade: iterators no longer working

Tags: php

I have a website which was working fine in XAMPP with PHP 5.6.

```
foreach ($treeNodeIterator as $nodeKey => $node) {

  $currentLevel = $nodeKey->getNodeLevel();

  if ($currentLevel > $depth) {

    $depth = $currentLevel;

  }

}
```

I then found out my server was running PHP 5.4. So now I get
the following error message on the server log file:

```
[13-Sep-2015 12:33:19 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getNodeLevel() on a non-object in treeNode.php line 82
```

Here is the TreeNodeIteratorKey class:

```
class TreeNode {

  protected $name;

  protected $value;

  protected $children;

  protected $customData;

  //...

}

class TreeNodeIterator implements Iterator {

  private $traversalMode;

  private $rootNode;

  private $nodesToVisit;

  private $nodesToVisitLevels;

  private $currentNodeIteratorKey;

  const TRAVERSAL_MODE_BFS = 0;

  const TRAVERSAL_MODE_DFS = 1;

  const NUM_TRAVERSAL_MODES = 2;

  public function current() {

    return $this->nodesToVisit[0];

  }

  public function key() {

    return $this->currentNodeIteratorKey;

  }


}

class TreeNodeIteratorKey {

  private $nodeIndex;

  private $nodeLevel;

  private $customData;

  //...
}
```

Comment: What kind of iterator? And wouldn't the `nodeKey`  just be a key anyway, and the `node` be an object?

Comment: Since I am iterating over TreeNodes, the Key is a custom object which embeds the node index and node level as part of the key.

Comment: You've posted two `TreeNodeIteratorKey` class definitions, was that intentional?

Comment: Anyway, that's a PHP 5.5 addition: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.non-scalar-iterator-keys - So, yes. No worky. Find a different approach.

Comment: How will I have to modify my code to find a different approach? I would like the minimal set of changes to get things to work.

Comment: Where can I find the cheapest PHP 5.6 hosting server? Any free ones?

Comment: I've tried one.com. First year free.

Comment: Worth noting: PHP 5.4 reached its end-of-life for security updates a few days ago. It's no longer safe to use.